# How do I label a page of the Galaxy S4 home screen?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-4, home-screen, home-screen-folders

The GS4 allows you to have multiple pages of the home screen.  I'd like to use this as a kind of full-screen, more accessible folder (e.g. a "Utilities" page).

How do I put a text label ("Utilities") to note the page as such?

I realize I could use an actual folder, but I'd like to try the page idea.